# How to partially upgrade Ubuntu 11.10 from Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: upgrade

I need to solve it. When update-manager upgrades, it does not continue from previous upgrading state. I want to partially upgrade because connection is going slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade using alternate-ubuntu iso 
it is better for slower connections
it may solve your problem